# Sphinx and Cloudflare couldnt work together ?

Tags: sphinx, cloudflare

I'm using sphinx search in fact i used to use . Cuz when buy cloudflare , and connect with my server , my sphinx cant work now .

are there anyone can help me?

Thanks for all

Comment: Not really clear how the two are related. They are very different technologies. Perhaps you can elaboate or provide examples/links showing the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it wouldn't work (don't know enough about that particular product). It looks like you install that particular product on your server directly, which we don't touch, so my first guess is that you don't have a required DNS setting in your CloudFlare DNS zone file related to that service.

Comment: and what i sould do for that? Really i have that ? on sphinx config listen localhost but my web server's ip not same with sphinx listen , can it be?